# Writing files to local system with Spark in Cluster mode

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I know this is a weird way of using Spark but I'm trying to save a dataframe to the local file system (not hdfs) using Spark even though I'm in `cluster mode`.  I know I can use `client mode` but **I do** want to run in `cluster mode` and don't care which node (out of 3) the application is going to run on as driver.
The code below is the pseudo code of what I'm trying to do.

```
// create dataframe
val df = Seq(Foo("John", "Doe"), Foo("Jane", "Doe")).toDF()
// save it to the local file system using 'file://' because it defaults to hdfs://
df.coalesce(1).rdd.saveAsTextFile(s"file://path/to/file")
```

And this is how I'm submitting the spark application.

`spark-submit --class sample.HBaseSparkRSample --master yarn-cluster hbase-spark-r-sample-assembly-1.0.jar`

This works fine if I'm in `local mode` but doesn't in `yarn-cluster mode`.

For example, `java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file` occurs with the above code.

I've changed the `df.coalesce(1)` part to `df.collect` and attempted to save a file using plain Scala but it ended up with a `Permission denied`.

I've also tried:

- `spark-submit` with `root` user
- `chown`ed `yarn:yarn`, `yarn:hadoop`, `spark:spark`
- gave `chmod 777` to related directories

but no luck.

I'm assuming this has to do something with `clusters`, `drivers and executors`, and the `user` who's trying to write to the local file system but am pretty much stuck in solving this problem by myself.

I'm using:

- Spark: 1.6.0-cdh5.8.2
- Scala: 2.10.5
- Hadoop: 2.6.0-cdh5.8.2

Any support is welcome and thanks in advance.

Some articles I've tried:

- "Spark saveAsTextFile() results in Mkdirs failed to create for half of the directory" -> Tried changing users but nothing changed
- "Failed to save RDD as text file to local file system" -> `chmod` didn't help me

## Edited (2016/11/25)

This is the Exception I get.

```
java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/home/foo/work/rhbase/r/input/input.csv/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201611242024_0000_m_000000_0 (exists=false, cwd=file:/yarn/nm/usercache/foo/appcache/application_1478068613528_0143/container_e87_1478068613528_0143_01_000001)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:813)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:135)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.open(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1185)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/11/24 20:24:12 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/home/foo/work/rhbase/r/input/input.csv/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201611242024_0000_m_000000_0 (exists=false, cwd=file:/yarn/nm/usercache/foo/appcache/application_1478068613528_0143/container_e87_1478068613528_0143_01_000001)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:920)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:813)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:135)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.open(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1185)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question because eventually, none of the answers didn't seem to solve my problem.  None the less, thanks for all the answers and pointing me to alternatives I can check.

I think @Ricardo was the closest in mentioning the user of the Spark application.  I checked `whoami` with `Process("whoami")` and the user was `yarn`.  The problem was probably that I tried to output to `/home/foo/work/rhbase/r/input/input.csv` and although `/home/foo/work/rhbase` was owned by `yarn:yarn`, `/home/foo` was owned by `foo:foo`.  I haven't checked in detail but this may have been the cause of this `permission` problem.

When I hit `pwd` in my Spark application with `Process("pwd")`, it output `/yarn/path/to/somewhere`.  So I decided to output my file to `/yarn/input.csv` and it was successful despite in `cluster mode`.

I probably can conclude that this was just a simple permission issue.  Any further solution would be welcome but for now, this was the way how I solved this question.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar question. I'm running spark code in cluster mode and writing few files using pandas, I think these files are written in yarn temp directory but I want to write them in HDFS, is there any a direct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you run the job as `yarn-cluster mode`, the driver will be running in any of the machine which is managed by YARN, so if `saveAsTextFile` has local file path, then it will store the output in any of the machine where driver is running.

Try running the job as `yarn-client mode` so the driver runs in the client machine

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I know its strange but I **do** want to run in `yarn-cluster mode`.  I have 3 nodes and I don't care which node the driver will be in.

Comment: but whichever node driver is running, there only the file will be created :)

Comment: why can't you store the data in hdfs path? you can run as yarn-cluster mode

Comment: the problem is that `saveAsTextFile` throws a `permission denied` exception and the driver node fails to write to the local file system. And I have a `shell script` that can only read from the local file system. That's why I cannot use hdfs... In addition, I cannot edit the script.  I know this is a weird way of using Spark.

Comment: Can you send the full log on permission denied error

Comment: My bad. It wasn't a `permission denied` but a `failed to create file`. I updated my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are trying to run/write the file with a user other than the Spark service. 
On that situation you can solve the permission issue by presetting the directory ACLs. Example:

```
setfacl -d -m group:spark:rwx /path/to/
```

(modify "spark" to your user group trying to write the file)

Answer (score 1):

Use forEachPartition method, and then for each partition get file system object and write one by one record to it, below is the sample code here i am writing to hdfs, instead you can use local file system as well

```
Dataset<String> ds=....

ds.toJavaRdd.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<String>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Iterator<String> iterator) throws Exception {

    final FileSystem hdfsFileSystem = FileSystem.get(URI.create(finalOutPathLocation), hadoopConf);

    final FSDataOutputStream fsDataOutPutStream = hdfsFileSystem.exists(finalOutPath)
            ? hdfsFileSystem.append(finalOutPath) : hdfsFileSystem.create(finalOutPath);


    long processedRecCtr = 0;
    long failedRecsCtr = 0;


    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        try {
            fsDataOutPutStream.writeUTF(iterator.next);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            failedRecsCtr++;
        }
        if (processedRecCtr % 3000 == 0) {
            LOGGER.info("Flushing Records");
            fsDataOutPutStream.flush();
        }
    }

    fsDataOutPutStream.close();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the spark documentation to understand the use of `--master` option in `spark-submit`.

- `--master local` is supposed to be used when running locally.
- `--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster` is supposed to be used when actually running on a yarn cluster.

Refer [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls) and [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/running-on-yarn.html#launching-spark-on-yarn).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply.  Does this mean I'm miss using the parameters?  My other spark applications do seem to work properly in cluster mode with the `yarn-cluster` parameter.  I'm going to edit my question, but I do want to run in cluster mode but want to save to the local file system even though I won't know which node it is going to be.