# Spark write Dataframes directly from Hive to local file system

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

This question is almost a replica of the requirement here: [Writing files to local system with Spark in Cluster mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786093/writing-files-to-local-system-with-spark-in-cluster-mode)

but my query is with a twist. The page above writes files from HDFS directly to local filesystem using spark but after converting it to RDD.

I'm in search of options available with just the Dataframe; conversion to RDD for huge data takes a toll on resource utilisation.

Comment: Why not just copy to local filesystem after writing to HDFS?

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of below syntax to directly write a dataframe to HDFS filesystem.

`df.write.format("csv").save("path in hdfs")`

Refer spark doc for more details: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#generic-loadsave-functions

Comment: Thanks. But my query was to write from HDFS to local, you are referring to the exact opposite. 
However, if I mention like this `save("file:///path/to/local")`, it'll save in local area.

But it never writes anything on local, creates a directory though. When I checked, it actually is creating the local files on the data nodes where the executors are running. I guess I've to lookout for something that brings the data from these executors to driver. In case you know how to, do tell.